# List of all diagonals in a matrix without using numpy - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

Let's say I got the following matrix:

```
[[5,4,3,2], [8,7,6,5], [4,3,2,0]]
```

I want to create 2 seperate functions that create a list of all diagonals from right to left, and from left to right without using the numpy module!

for e.x:

```
[[4], [8,3], [5,7,2], [4,6,0], [3,5], [2]]   # these are the right to left diagonals
```

I tried several different ways but with no success. also, I scanned stack overflow pretty massivly for answers, but did't find any that don't contain numpy.

edit: here is a code that I wrote that is supposed to handle some of the diagonals:

```
L = [[5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 6, 5], [4, 3, 2, 0]]


def search_diagonally_rtl(matrix):
    num_of_rows = len(matrix)
    num_of_cols = len(matrix[0])
    diag_mat = list()
    for i in range(0, num_of_rows):
        diag_mat.append([matrix[i][0]])
    row_index = 0
    for row in diag_mat:
        for k in range(0, row_index):
            i = k
            j = 1
            while i >= 0:
                row.append(matrix[i][j])
                i = i - 1
                j = j + 1
        row_index += 1
```

the output is: `[[5], [8, 4], [4, 4, 7, 3]]`

but should be : `[[5], [8, 4], [4, 7, 3]]`

Comment: Please add the code that you implemented yourself and tell us the idea behind it.

Comment: @Irreducible Thanks for the attention. but I have deleted all of my work since I had 0 success so far, so sadly I have nothing to show.

Comment: Reading [ask] you will see that SO is not a community to write code for you. You should add the code and an example with the desired input output behavior. Having all these information people will be able to help you understand where the mistake in your code / idea is

Comment: @Irreducible Thanks! will add code later!

Comment: @Irreducible Well I wrote a code that is supposed to handle some of the diagonals, but it seems to have some problems. can u take a look?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def diag1(x, startline):
    out = []
    line = startline
    col = 0
    while line < len(x) and col < len(x[0]):
        out.append(x[line][col])
        line +=1
        col += 1
    return out


def diag2(x, startcol):
    out = []
    line = 0
    col = startcol
    while line < len(x) and col < len(x[0]):
        out.append(x[line][col])
        line +=1
        col += 1
    return out


def diag(x):
    out = []
    for startline in range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1):
        out.append(diag1(x, startline))
    for startcol in range(1, len(x[0])):
        out.append(diag2(x, startcol))
    return out


x = [[5,4,3,2], [8,7,6,5], [4,3,2,0]]
print(diag(x))  # [[4], [8, 3], [5, 7, 2], [4, 6, 0], [3, 5], [2]]
```

`diag1` starts at the left border of the matrix and returns diagonals while `diag2` starts at the top border. `diag` combines the two methods.
Little adaptions need to made for the diagonals in the other direction.